# Assembly language getting the first, middle and last letter of an inputted word

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I'm making this project which the user will input two strings and the program will identify which is longer.

After that it will identify the first, middle, and last letter of the longest word.

I only manage to make it work if the 2nd word inputted is longer.. but when the first is longer I cant get the middle and last letter..please help .. Thanks :)

my code:

```
    .data
msg db "Enter 1st word: $"
msg1 db 13,10,"Enter 2nd word: $"
msg2 db "1st word is longer $"
msg3 db "2nd word is longer $"
msg4 db "1st letter is: $"
msg5 db "middle letter is $"
msg6 db "last letter is $"
ln db 13,10,10,"$"
str1 dw 20 
str2 dw 20
x db '0'

.code
main:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

lea si, str1
lea di, str2

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, si
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg1
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, di
int 21h


;counter 1st word
mov bx, 0h
mov bx, str1 + 1
mov cl,bl
;counter 2nd word
mov bx, 0h
mov bx, str2 + 1
mov al, bl

cmp cl, al
jg long
jl short

long:

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h



mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg2
int 21h
;first letter
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg4
int 21h

mov ah, 02
mov dl, si+2
int 21h

;/////////////////

;middle:
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg5
int 21h


mov bx, 0
mov bx, str1+1


mov ah, 0h
mov al, bl
mov bl, 02
div bl

mov ah, 0h
mov si, ax


mov bx,str1[si+4]
mov al,bl

mov ah, 02
mov dl, al
int 21h

;last
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg6
int 21h

mov bx, 0
mov bx, str1 + 1

mov bx, str1[si+6]
mov al, bl

mov ah, 02
mov dl,al
int 21h




jmp exit


short:

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg3
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h
;first letter        
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg4
int 21h

mov ah, 02
mov dl, di+2
int 21h
;/////////////////////// 

;middle:
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg5
int 21h


mov bx, 0
mov bx, str2+1


mov ah, 0h
mov al, bl
mov bl, 02
div bl

mov ah, 0h
mov di, ax


mov bx,str1[di+4]
mov al,bl

mov ah, 02
mov dl, al
int 21h

;last
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset ln
int 21h

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset msg6
int 21h

mov bx, 0
mov bx, str2 + 1

mov bx, str1[di+6]
mov al, bl

mov ah, 02
mov dl,al
int 21h




jmp exit

exit:
end main
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Describe your algorithm, provide test input and expected and actual output. Learn to use a debugger to step through the code to find your own mistakes.

Comment: A debugger would show something funny when you read the second word.

Comment: Please show the output for both the working case and the nonworking case.

Answer (score 0):

The code for both cases is wrong. The only reason one case seems to work is that you haven't tried enough tests. The +4 and +6 in the code where you load middle and last should both be +2. Double-check usage of str1 and str2. Set si and di before using them. That should get you a lot closer.

P.S. I'm intentionally not giving a full answer here, since you're trying to learn.